# Add Timestamp to File Name in Flash Media Server

Tags: flash-media-server

Is there some way to dynamically name files published in Flash Media server.

Several clients in an application will be publishing to FMS.  They may start and stop recording several times, and I would like to append a time stamp (format: yy-mm-dd-hh-mm-ss) to the file name in main.asc.

For example the following files might be created by clients 1 and 2 using the `ns.publish(myclientName);` command;

1. client1's first recording **client1_2011-01-01-22-47-01.flv**
2. client1's second recording **client1_2011-01-01-22-54-55.flv**
3. client2's first recording **client2_2011-01-01-22-59-34.flv**
4. client1's third recording **client1_2011-01-01-22-04-12.flv**

I don't want to use `ns.publish(myClientName, "append");`.  There needs to be a separate file for each publish session.

The best I can come up with is to use File.creationTime and File.renameTo() on application.onUnpublish() to add the timestamp when publishing has ended, but it it wouldn't be tolerant of an unexpected server outage.

**Edit:**  Unknown to me and in conflict with the documentation, the Date object in Flash Media Server is not the one we know and love.  It has no properties.  For example

```
var currentTime = new Date();
trace("CurrentTime: " +currentTime.time);
```

prints

> CurrentTime: undefined

Running

```
for (var prop in currentTime)
    trace(prop);
```

prints nothing.

I was surprised and frustrated after an hour or so to learn this.  Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

`currentTime.valueOf()` is timespan